# Any specific architectural solution for WPF apps that need to aggressively push refreshed data from Model to View?

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm, eventaggregator

Being new at MVVM and SOLID development, I’m working on a small WPF app, and I realized that my app is non-conventional in some ways:

- All of my Model data needs to be refreshed very often either by polling (every second), or by utilizing callback functions (e.g. with Shell hooks and `Automation` events).
- All refreshed data need to be pushed to the View immediately.
- The View is strictly a display for the data; it doesn't expose any kind of data mutation feature.

Currently I’m using the following, standard MVVM/DataBinding solution:

- My **Model** classes individually implement timer based polling or set up callbacks to keep their data up-to-date, and they implement the `INotifyPropertyChange` interface to notify the subscribers (the ViewModel) of all changes.
- My **ViewModel** subscribes to the instantiated Model objects’ `PropertyChanged` event. The ViewModel also implements the `INotifyPropertyChange` interface, and when it receives change notifications from the Model, it issues its own change notifications for the View. (Most ViewModel properties are simply wrapping the same Model properties, but the most important data, a collection of items, is converted to formatted HTML string to use in the View's `WebBrowser` control.)
- My **View** binds to the ViewModel as usual, and displays the updated data.

*The app will work with this design, but it doesn't feel right.*

## Are there some known development patterns for these one-way display-only scenarios?

In particular:

- Is it recommended to cut out the ViewModel, and expose all Model data specifically preformatted for the view? (No alternative views are planned for these data.)
- Is it possible to extend a single base class or implement an interface that somehow helps to centralize the polling/callbacks/change-notification responsibilities?

---

**This is how the unfinished/incomplete Model looks like now:**

You can roughly see the current state of the dependencies. (I'm sure there are a lot of issues with this model.)

[image]

Comment: In what way does it not feel right?  The entire point of this pattern is to dynamically update the view when the observable content changes, regardless of whether or not two way binding is present.  What is the actual problem that you're running into?

Comment: @DavidL, I can't really put my finger on it to be honest; it just doesn't seem elegant and well structured - I'm using multiple timers in different objects, and pushing changes from various places. I was hoping for some centralized messaging pattern (?) to clean it up a bit. (I would like to use this app partly as a reference project, so I want to make sure I'm implementing the best solutions for the given scenario.)

Comment: If you need messaging, you should consider using something like MVVM Light.  It does a solid job of providing a messaging pattern for distributed data.

Comment: @DavidL, thanks, I'll look into it. Otherwise you think my design sounds fine?

Comment: Without knowing anything about your actual application or seeing any of the real code, sure, it seems reasonable.  Observables are the core pattern for data updates in WPF.  Right now your question is too broad to definitively answer, but message brokering would clean up your data redundancy/timer concerns.

Answer (score 2):

To the particulars:

1. Yes, you can have a MainViewModel as DataContext to your View, and take out polling from the model to a Service, which the VM can listen to its event like 'ThereWereChangesEvent' and then update your collection(have a collection of 'Model's first) of items accordingly.
2. answer 1 actually answers that too. Write an external service and use it.
   it can aggregate change notifications from the models and let them propegate by raising 'ThereWereChangesEvent' with a couple of them together.

hope this helps..

Comment: Definitely helps, thanks! Though, I'll need to look into this in more detail before I accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

For simple read only view of data-streams, choosing a good library can also help you with the architecture design. Please have a look at [Rx.Net](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET) https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET You can has a stream of business objects and convert it into a stream of ViewModels and bind the ViewModels to UI.