# How to express dependencies explicitly when using Event Aggregator?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, eventaggregator

This is my first time using an Event Aggregator, so apologies if I'm overlooking or misunderstanding something completely obvious.

- In my MVVM project, I have multiple model classes that depend on the same, periodically updating data, and they need to react to the changes of the data. (Some of these classes produce their own data based on this dependency, which also need to be sent to yet other classes.)
- Instead of injecting this same dependency into multiple model classes and using `INotifyPropertyChange` / `PropertyChanged`, I want to use Caliburn Micro's `EventAggregator` to publish and handle the refreshed data.

**My concern is that implementing the `EventAggregator` solution seems to hide the dependencies between various classes, since their explicit dependency will be the `EventAggregator`.**

So, the following in my composition root (obviously just an example code):

```
_dependency = new Dependency();
_dependent1 = Dependent1(_dependency);
_dependent2 = Dependent2(_dependency);
...
```

Will become the following, if I'm correct:

```
_eventAggregator = new EventAggregator();
_dependency = new Dependency(_eventAggregator); // Publishes
_dependent1 = Dependent1(_eventAggregator); // Handles
_dependent2 = Dependent2(_eventAggregator); // Handles
...
```

**Notes:**

- Caliburn Micro contains a generic `IHandle<T>` interface that can be used to express the handling of certain types of objects.
- But it doesn't have a corresponsing `IPublish<T>` interface to explicitly express the publishing of certain types of objects. And even that wouldn't constitute a compile time check for a matching `IPublish<T>` – `IHandle<T>` pair.
- Also, my composition root will be hard to read, because it will lack the information about actual dependency hierarchy (which can be substituted by comments, but still).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My concern is that implementing the EventAggregator solution seems to hide the dependencies between various classes, since their explicit dependency will be the EventAggregator.

Well, that's the purpose of using an event aggregator. All classes only knows about the event aggregator itself but they don't know anything or have any dependencies upon each other. This means that you can modify one class without affecting another one.

So of course they do have a dependency upon the event aggregator but this is better than keeping a direct reference to each subscriber from each publisher class.

Obviously the publisher needs to publish an event at some point if the subscriber is dependant on this event somehow. But this is the same even if you have a strong reference to the publisher class from the subscriber.

Comment: I was excepting your answer; I saw that you're a frequent answerer on these tags. :) Do you think there is a way I could guarantee (at compile time) that, if a handler of X exist, then there is a corresponding publisher of X?

Comment: If you need these kind of guarantee, it makes no sense to use an event aggregator. Then you might as well have a direct reference to the publisher and hook up to an event of it using the += syntax. This is the way to guarantee that the event actually exists at compile-time.

Comment: Thanks; I suspected that I might be confused about the use cases. What I mostly wanted is to centralize the messaging between classes, based on the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837723/any-specific-architectural-solution-for-wpf-apps-that-need-to-aggressively-push) - but still keeping this guarantee, yes.

Comment: The event aggregator removes the tight coupling between publishers and subscribers but this obviously also removes the "guarantee" that you are talking about. Please refer to the following blog post for more information about this: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/

Comment: Sorry about that :). Try again now.

Comment: Thank you, I'm reading it! :) Too bad I managed to post another, not very useful question, based on a confusion; I'll think about how to reformulate it to make it more useful for future visitors.